# Trying to programatically create multiple relative layouts within a ViewFlipper

Tags: android, android-layout, viewflipper, android-relativelayout

I am trying to programatically create a multiple `RelativeLayouts` inside a `ViewFlipper`.
I'm doing this in order to build a dynamic `ViewFlipper` that holds N number of images, N changes.

I am trying to create something like that: (that works BTW..)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/lightning" />

<TextView
    style="@style/ImageTitle"
    android:text="@string/lightning" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/color_baloons" />

<TextView
    style="@style/ImageTitle"
    android:text="@string/color_baloons" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/natural_wall" />

<TextView
    style="@style/ImageTitle"
    android:text="@string/natural_wall" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ViewFlipper>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/swipe_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/swipe_left" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/swipe_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/swipe_right" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my code:

Problem: I don't see the images

What am I missing?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_image_layout);
    _context = this;
    _viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    _imageUrls = intent.getStringArrayExtra("theImageUrl");

    for (int i = 0; i < _imageUrls.length; i++) {

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(_context);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(_context);
        LayoutParams imageParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        File file = new File(_imageUrls[i]);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        final String imagePathFromUri = uri.getPath();

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapHelper.loadImageFromUrl(
                "file://" + _imageUrls[i],
                imagePathFromUri,
                BUFFER_IO_SIZE);

        if (bitmap != null) {

            final Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(
                    getResources(),
                    bitmap);

            if (drawable != null) {
                imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
            }
        }


        TextView textView = new TextView(_context);
        textView.setTextAppearance(_context, R.style.ImageTitle);

        layout.addView(imageView);
        layout.addView(textView);

        _viewFlipper.addView(layout);
    }

    _viewFlipper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to add some logs to find out where it fails. For example, is bitmap != null true? What about drawable != null?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. I am debugging on the device and everything is looking good. No nulls or anything..

Comment: Do you see your TextView? Could the TextView hide the ImageView (has your R.style.ImageTitle got a background colour?)? Out of curiosity, why aren't you using a list or a grid? Seems like you are trying something quite complicated (never recommended to programmatically draw views like that)

Comment: I see the area of the image and the area bellow of the text but nothing in them. The style is good. as for the complexity, I took the idea of the xml code above from someone to slide images and I just wanted to create it in code..

Comment: Ok, I changed the textview background color and it changed it. I have set ImageView background color to red (in code of course) instead of setting the bitmap and i didn't see the red.. where is the image?!

Comment: Found It! In my activity layout I had a relative layout inside the ViewFlipper already so it kept showing it instead of my imageviews.. Stupid mistake of mine..